# filter packages that can be reconfigured with dpkg-reconfigure

Tags: dpkg, 19.10

How can I filter packages, that can be reconfigured with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure packagename
```

Example: exim4 grub-pc  libdvd-pkg a.s.o

Is this possible over

```
debconf-get-selections
```

I hope this is no duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
debconf-show --listowners
```

From `man debconf-show`:

> ```
>    --listowners
>        Lists all owners of questions in the database. Generally an owner
>        is equivalent to a debian package name.
> ```

"having questions in the database" is equivalent to "being reconfigurable" I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot @steeldriver.